# Cómo identificar los permisos en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Estoy tratando de verificar los permisos de un usuario con el método `has_perm()` de la clase `User`, pero no logro identificar el permiso correctamente usando la notación especificada en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions).

Primero voy a traer a un usuario normal:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate  
>>> user = authenticate(username='fulano', password='abc123')
>>> print(user)
fulano
```

Tengo una *app* llamada `rechazos` y verifico que esté configurada:

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>>  apps.app_configs

OrderedDict([('auth', <AuthConfig: auth>),
             ('contenttypes', <ContentTypesConfig: contenttypes>),
             # apps no relacionadas....
             ('acreditacion', <AcreditacionConfig: acreditacion>),
             ('users', <UsersConfig: users>),
             ('rechazos', <RechazosConfig: rechazos>),
             ('debug_toolbar', <DebugToolbarConfig: debug_toolbar>)])
```

Ahí puedo ver mi aplicación `rechazos`...

Ahora verifico los permisos de mi usuario:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
>>> permisos = Permission.objects.filter(user=user)
>>> print(permisos)
<QuerySet [<Permission: rechazos | causa | Can add causa>]>
```

Puedo ver que tiene un permiso: la aplicación es `rechazos`, el modelo es `causa`, el permiso es: `Can add causa`.

Entonces utilizo el método `has_perm()` del modelo [`models.User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perms) y no obtengo el resultado esperado.

```
>>> user.has_perms('rechazos.causa.can_add_causa')   
False
```

El resultado debería ser positivo, pero como ven, es negativo.

Como supongo que es por la forma en la que describo el permiso, pruebo con  las siguientes combinaciones, igualmente sin éxito:

```
>>> user.has_perm('apps.rechazos.causa.can_add_causa')
>>> user.has_perm('apps.rechazos.can_add_causa')
```

#### Pregunta:

> Dado el modelo `rechazos.causa`, como puedo verificar, **usando el método `has_perms()`** que un usuario tiene el permiso llamado *`Can add causa`*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase `models.User` tiene un método llamado [`get_all_permissions()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_all_permissions) que cuando se llama sin argumentos devuelve un conjunto (*set*) que contiene todos los permisos del usuario, incluyendo los permisos obtenidos por los grupos.

En el caso de esta pregunta, esta es la identificación de los permisos:

```
>>> user.get_all_permissions()
{'rechazos.add_causa'}
```

Y la solución a la pregunta es:

```
>>> user.has_perms(['rechazos.add_causa']) 
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación para consultar un permiso de forma individual debería ser de la siguiente forma:

[Permiso individual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm)

```
>>> user.has_perm('rechazos.can_add_causa')
```

Y para consultar por multiples permisos:

[Multiples permisos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_module_perms)

```
>>> user.has_perms(['rechazos.can_add_causa'])
```

Solo debes incluir el nombre de la aplicación y el nombre del permiso.

Comment: Pues esta opción también me sale `False`.

Comment: ¿Tu permiso es personalizado? ¿Usaste permissions en el Meta de tu clase? si no usaste nada de eso tu permiso debería ser `rechazos.add_causa` y no `rechazos.can_add_causa`